# how to access cookies globally in nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am just reading Nuxt3 useCookie & getCookie.
i want to understand how to get cookies everywhere around the application, without declaring useCookie on everypage or component.

for example
**this is component CurrencySwitcher.vue**

```
<script setup>

const UserCurrency = useCookie("UserCurrency", {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
});

//use this to change & set currency.
const SetCurrency = (item) => {
  UserCurrency.value = item;
  window.location.reload(true);
};

//here we pass something like this in UserCurrency Cookie.
  {
    code: "EUR",
    name: "Euro"
  }

</script>
```

Now my Question is.
How to use this **UserCurrency** in other components or pages without declaring useCookie everywhere.

for Example,
now there is other ProductCard component, where i need to use CurrencyCode with Price or I need to use that in useFetch.

```
<template>
<card>
<h3>Product Price : {{UserCurrency.code}} {{Cost}}</h3>
</card>
</template>
```

or

```
<script setup>
const AllProducts = await useFetch(`SomeApiRoute?currency=${UserCurrency.code}`)
</script>
```

how to use cookies inline in both the case.

Comment: Cookies are always global per-se, it's baked-in into your browser.

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding. you have to use composable inside the place you want to use it.. this actually the purpose of composable .. it hides the implementation inside composable and you can just use it simply by adding useCookie .. etc